# Datastore replication: help characterize legacy system topology

Tags: java, esb, distributed-computing, distributed-transactions

A new system has been built to gradually assume the responsibilities of the legacy one. Both collaborate in production.

To facilitate this, they share a replicated domain object model. Both use relatively primitive, in memory objects stores. The legacy system is the canonical store, and every change in it is replicated to the new one via ESB. The new system may modify some objects, which the legacy system polls for and updates its master data.

The two systems may sometimes call an API endpoint on the other to issue a command, but often communicate such commands implicitly by modifying shared objects.

There is no concept of transactions or batch updates. The new system uses a global write lock to process all updates and refresh object references in its in-memory store. Mass deletion or insertion of datasets, or sequential object graph construction or deletion can hog the new system's global write lock. It is brittle, slow and difficult to develop and test with.

The legacy system was build in C++, the new one in Java. This also adds an object translation layer.

I'm tasked with improving stability and performance. I see it as a database replication problem, and want to draw on established literature and maybe open source products, but am struggling to characterize it.

What standard topologies are most applicable here?